# How to move the li element to particular position?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<ul id="listcomments">
   <li>Comment 1</li>
   <li>Comment 2</li>
   <li>Comment 3</li>
   <li>Comment 4</li>
   <li>Comment 5 </li>
   <li>Comment 6</li>
   <li>Comment 7</li>
   <li>Comment 8</li>
   <li>Child comment of #5 is this</li>
</ul>
```

In the above element , i need to **move** comment 8 li next to the comment 2 li using **jquery**. How to achieve it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use this:

```
  $( "#listcomments" ).sortable();
```

Check this link. https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#listcomments li:eq(7)').insertAfter("#listcomments li:nth-child(1)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listcomments">
    <li>Comment 1</li>
    <li>Comment 2</li>
    <li>Comment 3</li>
    <li>Comment 4</li>
    <li>Comment 5 </li>
    <li>Comment 6</li>
    <li>Comment 7</li>
    <li>Comment 8</li>
    <li>Child comment of #5 is this</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Jquery UI Sortable` to achieve what you want.

```js
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

[Jquery UI Sortable Reference](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of jquery and nth-child selector you can do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li:nth-child(8)').css({
'color':'red',
'position':'absolute',
'left':'400px',
'top':'34px'
});
})
```

See the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/o3gn55n6/2/

NOTE: With the code provided only, I have created the fiddle and put the values.
But you can do what you want with that by changing values according to your need. For more flexibility you would want to post the entire context of your code.

This is cross-browser compatible.
See for nth-child jquery here :
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_nthchild.asp

Essentially you would want your li 8th element to be flexible to be put in desired place.